# Rule for route and on "." or "/"

Tags: php, web, yii, yii2

I want to configure  url manager . I need if  route match  /deti/festival.  or /deti/festival/  Yii enable Deti controller and festival action, but now for this requests yii return  404 , what's  wrong? If i use option 'suffix'=>'/'  rule  /deti/festival/  work , but other   rules  don't  work .
What i must do ?

```
'urlManager'=>[
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules'=>[
            'messages' => 'lk/default/messages',
            'students' => 'lk/student/index',
            'ulogin/ulogin' => '/reg/ulogin/ulogin',
            'ulogin/auth' => '/reg/ulogin/auth',
            'lk/anketa/auth' => '/lk/auth/auth',
            'lk/anketa/logout' => '/lk/auth/logout',
            'deti' => '/deti/deti',
            'festival'=>'/deti/deti/view?id=562',
            '/deti/festival'=>'/deti/deti/festival',
            '/deti/eco'=>'/deti/deti/eco',
            '/deti/festival[.\/]?'=>'/deti/deti/festival',
            '/deti/eco/'=>'/deti/deti/eco',
            '/profile/exhview.php'=>'/exhibitions/default/old',
            '/profile/user.php'=>'/profile/profile/old'
        ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

for suffix, you can write url rules like below.

```
'rules' => [
    // ...other url rules...
    [
        'pattern' => 'deti/festival',
        'route' => 'deti/deti/festival',
        'suffix' => '/',
    ],
]
```